# Rails booking rendez-vous API

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a project and i want to add booking rendezvous service using Ruby on Rails. Is there any API for booking ? ay tutorial for that ?

P.S
I already searched for any tutorial but I didn't find it.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Did you checkout `acts_as_bookable` gem ?

Comment: Since you are new to SO, would recommend you to go through this post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: And for the future, In case you want to know if there are any gem exist to accomplish such task you may want to checkout this site: http://awesome-ruby.com/ . all the best